# consulta json php con resultados duplicados

Tags: php, android, mysql, json

El resultado de mi consulta php  se muestra de la siguiente forma:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

se repiten los datos en cada consulta.

```
            <?php
            header('Content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8');
            include('functions.php');
            $sql = "SELECT * FROM `mitabla`";
            function connectDB()
            {
                $server = "mihost";
                $user   = "miusr";
                $pass   = "mipass";
                $bd     = "mibd";
                $conexion = mysqli_connect($server, $user, $pass, $bd);
                mysqli_set_charset($enlace, "utf8");
                if ($conexion) {
                } else {
                }
                return $conexion;
            }
            function disconnectDB($conexion)
            {
                $close = mysqli_close($conexion);
                if ($close) {
                } else {
                }
                return $close;
            }
            function getArraySQL($sql)
            {
                $conexion = connectDB();
                mysqli_set_charset($conexion, "utf8"); 
                if (!$result = mysqli_query($conexion, $sql))
                    die(); 
                $rawdata = array(); 

                $i = 0;
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                     $rawdata[$i] = $row;
                     $i++;
                }

                disconnectDB($conexion); 
                return $rawdata; 
            }
            $myArray = getArraySQL($sql);
            echo json_encode($myArray, JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE | JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES | WITHOUT_ARRAY_WRAPPER),"\n";
            ?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

El *quid* de la cuestión está en la definición del método [*`mysqli_fetch_array`*](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php):

> Obtiene una fila de resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, **o
> ambos**.

El ***o ambos***, que he puesto intencionalmente en negritas, significa que si no indicas el tipo de array que quieres, la función asumirá que quieres un estilo `MYSQLI_BOTH` (valor por defecto) el cual creará un array tanto asociativo como numérico. Por eso tus datos se duplican.

La duplicidad desaparecerá cuando indiques cómo quieres el array. Esto se puede comprender al leer el apartado `resulttype`en el Manual:

> **`resulttype`**
> Este parámetro opcional es una constante que indica qué tipo de array debiera generarse con la información de la fila
> actual. Los valores posibles para este parámetro son las constantes
> `MYSQLI_ASSOC`, `MYSQLI_NUM`, o `MYSQLI_BOTH`.

---

### Soluciones

Puedes entonces indicar cómo quieres tus datos.

#### *a) Arreglo asociativo:*

```
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_ASSOC)) {
                 $rawdata[] = $row;
            }
```

O bien:

Puesto que el Manual dice que:

> Al emplear la constante `MYSQLI_ASSOC` esta función se comportará de manera idéntica a [`mysqli_fetch_assoc()`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php)

Podemos hacerlo del siguiente modo, usando dicha función:

```
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
                 $rawdata[] = $row;
            }
```

#### *b) Arreglo numérico:*

```
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result,MYSQLI_NUM)) {
                 $rawdata[] = $row;
            }
```

O bien:

Puesto que el Manual dice que:

> ... con `MYSQLI_NUM` se comportará exactamente igual que la función [`mysqli_fetch_row()`](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-row.php)

Podemos hacerlo del siguiente modo, usando dicha función:

```
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_row($result)) {
                 $rawdata[] = $row;
            }
```

**NÓTESE:** Que no es necesario implementar un contador `$i`, como estabas haciendo al principio. El array se creará solo, sin necesidad de ese contador.

Comment: @mono101 En caso de que la respuesta te haya ayudado a resolver el problema, por favor, cuando sea posible l◔_◔: [¿Qué debo hacer cuando alguien contesta mi pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers) en el Centro de Ayuda.