# ¿Qué significa "rw" en un código que itera sobre resultados de una base de datos?

Tags: php

Tengo una duda sobre que puede significar `rw` en este código:

```
<label>Filtrar por categoría</label>
    <select class='form-control' name='id_categoria' id='id_categoria' onchange="load(1);">
        <option value="">Selecciona una categoría</option>
        <?php 
        $query_categoria=mysqli_query($con,"select * from categorias order by nombre_categoria");
        while($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($query_categoria)) {
            ?>
        <option value="<?php echo $rw['id_categoria'];?>"><?php echo $rw['nombre_categoria'];?></option>            
            <?php
        }
        ?>
    </select>
```

Es decir, allí donde por ejemplo se ve:

```
$rw=mysqli_fetch_array($query_categoria)
```

Parece que se usa mucho esta nomenclatura pero ¿qué puede significar? ¿rewrite?

Comment: Signfica row, es solo declaracion de variable

Comment: Como te dice @JorgeBowen, es simplemente el nombre de una variable, su nombre es arbitrario. Usar `$rw` no es precisamente una nomenclatura muy usada ni extendida (quizá sólo por el autor de los artículos que estás consultando) y ni tan siquiera recomendada (tú mismo has sufrido el efecto de una mala interpretación del efecto de acortar el nombre), ya que lo normal es poner `$row` de manera completa (así te lo recomendarán la mayoría de autores) y así identificar unívocamente el uso y/o contenido de la variable.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### En cuanto nombre

En cuanto a *nombre*  podría significar *row* (fila).

Como ha comentado acertadamente @OscarGarcia, conviene una aclaración sobre esto:

> Parece que se usa mucho esta nomenclatura pero ¿qué puede significar?
>   ¿rewrite?

Realmente nombrar ese objeto como `$rw` no es parte de ninguna nomenclatura conocida. Si observas [los ejemplos de código del Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php), podrás ver que ese objeto por lo general se llama `$row`. No conviene ser demasiado tacaños al nombrar nuestras variables/objetos. Precisamente aquí, por ahorrarte una letra, creas un nombre que puede confundirse con `rewrite`, mientras que si lo nombras `$row`, es inequívoco.

Y ya que tocamos el tema, puede ser en inglés. Incluso puedes tomar el hábito de nombrar tus variables y métodos en inglés. El código es más universal, los nombres de variables/métodos son más simples y no encontrarás los escollos que presentan la `ñ`, las palabras acentuadas y demás. Evitarás escribir variables como `myAnio` para no declarar una variable risible :).

### En cuanto objeto

Significa lo que devolvería `mysqli_fetch_array`.

El [Manual de PHP](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-array.php) explica lo que este método devuelve:

> Obtiene una fila de resultados como un array asociativo, numérico, o
>   ambos.

Al hacer esto:

```
while($rw=mysqli_fetch_array($query_categoria)) {
    //código
}
```

Lo que se abre es como un puntero que empezará a recorrer fila por fila los resultados que trajo la ejecución de la consulta, para irlos presentando en pantalla o guardando en otro objeto para transferirlos a otra parte.

Es la forma óptima de leer resultados, sobre todo cuando la consulta podría traer muchas filas y traerlas todas de golpe causaría problemas de memoria.

---

### Recomendación de optimización

Viendo que piensas usar los resultados así:

```
$rw['id_categoria']
```

Te conviene usar mejor la función  [**`mysqli_fetch_assoc`**](http://php.net/manual/es/mysqli-result.fetch-assoc.php), la cual:

> Obteniene una fila de resultado como un array asociativo.

Y es que como dice la definición de `mysqli_fetch_array`, te crea un arreglo asociativo y otro numérico. El array numérico no lo vas a usar, y por tanto el código se va a cargar más <sup>1</sup>.

Tu código puede ser escrito así:

```
//Voy a sacar la o de la caja de ahorrs para usarla
while($row=mysqli_fetch_assoc($query_categoria)) {
    //código
}
```

Leyendo dentro del bucle los datos como `$row['columna']`, eso es lo que se conoce como arreglo asociativo, que crea un resultado en forma de array donde cada clave es el nombre de la columna asociada a su valor respectivo.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Eso ocurrió por ejemplo en esta pregunta: [consulta json php con resultados duplicados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/199350/29967), donde no se entendía por qué los resultados venían *duplicados*. El motivo era precisamente que `fetch_array`, tal y como dice su definición, **traía un resultado asociado de forma numérica y otro asociado por nombre de columna**. Esto afecta el rendimiento, sobre todo en resultados grandes.</sub>

Comment: Dos +1, para esta respuesta y la relacionada. Sólo un apunte: la pérdida de rendimiento es mínima ya que cualquiera de los dos métodos trabajan sobre el mismo *result set* de MySQL, sólo cambia el uso en memoria puntual de ambos índices duplicados, el código de ambas funciones se comparte (es prácticamente idéntico, [ver código fuente](https://github.com/php/php-src/blob/master/ext/mysqli/mysqli.c#L1190), aunque en el caso del `fetch_assoc` hay una comprobación adicional respecto al `fetch_num` y una llamada extra al comienzo a `mysql_fetch_fields` para obtener el nombre de los campos).

Comment: Gracias @OscarGarcia, cuando hablo de la pérdida de rendimiento me refiero al hecho de traer dos veces los mismos datos, uno con asociación numérica y otro con asociación de nombre de columna (la imagen de la otra pregunta lo muestra). O sea, si se usa `fetch_array` sin más, cada `$rw` será más grande, traerá datos como `[0] Valor1, [Valor1]Valor1 ... `

Comment: Gracias por responder tan rápido. También te agradecería que agregaras un apunte sobre lo que él considera *"que se usa mucho esta nomenclatura"* para dejar claro que forma parte de ninguna nomenclatura estándar y, además, no es recomendable acortar el nombre de una variable si puede inducir, como le ha pasado a él, a error en la interpretación de su uso o contenido.

Comment: @OscarGarcia muchas gracias por tu acertado comentario, con el cual he podido mejorar la respuesta. Saludos.