# ¿Cómo introducir las 10 primeras filas de una tabla en un array multidireccional de con método procedimental?

Tags: php, mysql

¿Cómo podríamos introducir las 10 primeras filas (las marcadas con fondo azul), en un array multidireccional?

1)CONSULTA SQL

```
$consutla="SELECT * FROM preguntasDeAnimales ORDER BY numeroPregunta ASC LIMIT 10";
```

2)FUNCIÓN MYSQLI_FETCH_ROW Y ASIGNACIÓN MEDIANTE FOR (NO LO CONSIGO):

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);
$numeros_filas = mysqli_num_rows($result);
    if($numeros_filas>0){
        //METEMOS LOS 10 RESULTADOS EN UN ARRAY MULTIDIMENSIONAL
        if($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoSi)){
//AQUÍ IRÍA LA ASIGNACIÓN AL ARRAY MULTIDIMENSIONAL... ¿SUPONGO QUE CON DOS FOR?
}
```

[image: Tabla ejemplo con]

(Decir que el contenido de la tabla son simplemente ejemplos)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

El problema de tu código está sobre todo aquí:

```
       //METEMOS LOS 10 RESULTADOS EN UN ARRAY MULTIDIMENSIONAL
        if($filas = mysqli_fetch_array($resultadoSi)){
//AQUÍ IRÍA LA ASIGNACIÓN AL ARRAY MULTIDIMENSIONAL... ¿SUPONGO QUE CON DOS FOR?
```

Porque `$resultadoSi` no representa a tu conjunto de resultados, porque no necesitas evaluar nada con `if` (ya verificaste antes si hay más de `0` filas) y porque no necesitas dos `for` como hace pensar el comentario de tu código.

También hay un error de sintaxis, tu variable la has llamado <s>`$consutla`</s>.

Visto esto, paso a explicar algo:

Al ejecutar `mysqli_query`, si todo va bien, vas a tener en `$result` algo así como un puntero con los resultados. Entonces, si quieres guardar esos resultados en un array tendrías que usar algunos de los métodos `fetch` con que cuenta mysqli para leer datos recorriendo el puntero fila por fila (esto se hace así para evitar problemas de memoria, sobre todo en eventuales resultados con miles o millones de filas).

El que los datos están en un puntero significa que los puedes recorrer dentro de un bucle, fila por fila. Generalmente esto se hace con un `while` como se mostrará en la respuesta. Al hacer por ejemplo: `while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {` empezamos a recorrer los resultados fila por fila. O sea el puntero se va moviendo fila por fila en los resultados y cada vez `$row` representará la fila actual. Entonces podemos tener una array previamente declarado al que iremos asignando el valor de `$row` (la fila con cada columna y su valor).

Veamos todo esto aplicado en código concreto. Nótese que he corregido el nombre de tu variable que tiene el `SELECT`:

```
$consulta="SELECT * FROM preguntasDeAnimales ORDER BY numeroPregunta ASC LIMIT 10";

$result = mysqli_query($con,$consulta);
$numeros_filas = mysqli_num_rows($result);
$arrData=array();

if($numeros_filas>0){
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result) ) {
        $arrData[]=$row;
    }
}
```

Te recomiendo que evites el uso de `mysqli_fetch_array`, dando preferencia a una función de guardado más específica. El problema es que `mysqli_fetch_array` te crea un array numérico y otro asociativo. O sea, que te trae los datos dos veces, recargando la memoria<sup>1</sup>.

Aquí he usado `mysqli_fetch_assoc` que crear un array asociativo donde la clave es el nombre de la columna y el valor es el dato que hay en esa columna. En esa caso, para mostrar un dato sería algo así: `$row["Pregunta"]`  o bien así, dando por hecho que los datos se guardarán en el array resultante: `$arrData["Pregunta"]`.

Si por el contrario te interesa un array numérico (que asocie los valores no por nombre de columnas, sino por números), sólo cambias la línea del `while` por esto:

```
    while ( $row = mysqli_fetch_row($result) ) {
```

y para recuperar cada dato, usarías los índices numéricos: `$row[0]` por ejemplo o `$arrData[0]` ... ten en cuenta que siempre puedes usar `var_dump` o `print_r` para ver cómo está constituido tu array resultante.

Espero te sea de utilidad.

---

<sub>**Notas:**</sub>

1. Es el problema que ocurre en esta pregunta: [consulta json php con resultados duplicados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/199350/29967) . El OP estaba obteniendo datos duplicados y no entendía por qué. El motivo era que estaba usando `mysqli_fetch_array` para obtener el resultado de la consulta.

Comment: Gracias por la acotación. Y la explicación. Uno aprende algo nuevo todos los días. Solía usar `mysqli_fetch_array` siempre. Ahora entiendo que tal vez no era lo más indicado. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

no soy muy experto con PHP, pero creo que esto te podría ayudar:

```js
//nuestro array
$array = array();

//nuestra consulta
$consulta="SELECT * FROM preguntasDeAnimales ORDER BY numeroPregunta ASC LIMIT 10";

// intentamos el query
if($result = mysqli_query($con,$consulta)) {
  // si el query devuelve 'true' obtenemos las filas
  while($fila = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
    //aqui guardamos el array de fila en nuestro array
    array_push($array,$fila);
  }
  // buena práctica esto de cerrar 'result'
  mysqli_free_result($result);
}

// hemos terminado
// ahora 'array' tiene la información que necesitas.
```

Espero que te sirva, como dije antes, no soy muy experto en PHP, si hay un error me corriges.

Saludos.

Comment: Evita la mezcla de estilos: procedural por un lado `mysqli_query` y orientado a objetos por otro lado `$result -> fecth_row()` ... es una mala práctica. También para este caso creo que en vez de `fetch_row` sería mejor usar `fetch_assoc`.

Comment: Se agradecen las respuestas. Sí, estoy buscando la solución por procedimientos. No se si Mauricio Contreras podría modificar su respuesta a Procedimental. Lo agradecería.

Comment: Uuuups, si. Mezclé las cosas. Hace algún tiempo que no programo en PHP y esto sucede cuando estás fuera de forma. Déjame replantear la respuesta usando un enfoque procedimental, ya que veo que estás trabajando así. Gracias @ACedano por tu comentario

Comment: Bueno, ya tienes 2 respuestas. A.

Comment: Ya modifiqué la respuesta a enfoque procedimental. Aún así, si hay fallas me corriges. Saludos