# Json array listas

Tags: php, json, array

tengo el siguiente codigo para recorrer un listado de json...
Al imprimir el json lo hace de manera muy desordenada e incluso se repiten muchos datos.

Que esta mal?

```
<?php


    include_once "conexion.php";

    $sql_registros = mysqli_query($conexion,"SELECT * FROM clientes ORDER BY id ASC");
    
    while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_array($sql_registros)) {
        
        $json[] = $resultado;
    }

    echo json_encode($json,JSON_UNESCAPED_UNICODE);

    

?>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`mysqli_fetch_array` te devuelve los datos dos veces, con índice numérico y con índice asociativo, o sea que si tienes por ejemplo las columnas: `id, nombre, apellido` y usas `mysqli_fetch_array` vas a tener por cada fila algo así:

```
0 :       1
id:       1
1 :       Pedro
nombre:   Pedro
2 :       Díaz
apellido: Díaz
----
0 :       2
id:       2
1 :       Marta
nombre:   Marta
2 :       Pérez
apellido: Pérez
----
etc ...
```

Ves dos veces `1`, dos veces `Pedro`, dos veces `Díaz`, etc por lo ya dicho: `mysqli_fetch_array()` hace dos tipos de agrupación con los resultados.

De modo que conviene usar un **método más específico**. Si te interesan las claves asociativas (que es lo que se suele usar en JSON), entonces puedes ponerlo así:

```
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_assoc($sql_registros)) {
    $json[] = $resultado;
}
```

En ese caso, tu resultado será este:

```
id:       1
nombre:   Pedro
apellido: Díaz
----
id:       2
nombre:   Marta
apellido: Pérez
----
etc ...
```

Si por el contrario te interesan las claves numéricas, puedes ponerlo así:

```
while ($resultado = mysqli_fetch_row($sql_registros)) {
    $json[] = $resultado;
}
```

Y tu resultado será este:

```
0 :       1
1 :       Pedro
2 :       Díaz
----
0 :       2
1 :       Marta
2 :       Pérez
----
etc ...
```

En resumen, `mysqli_fetch_assoc()` y `mysqli_fetch_row()` son métodos más específicos para obtener datos, según queramos un array asociativo o numérico.

Este problema ya fue tratado con detalle en la [respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/199387/29967) aceptada de la pregunta: *[consulta json php con resultados duplicados](https://es.stackoverflow.com/q/199350/29967)*.